# What is the meaning of blue class symbol with a quarter green in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

What is the meaning of the symbol below?
[image: The symbol in android studio intelliJ: A blue circle that has a quarter slice of it colored green. It has a 'C' in the center.]

I couldn't find this symbol in [IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2 Help - Symbols](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html).

Answer (score 2):

This represents a Abstract class.

[image: Screenshot of editor. On the left is a code hierarchy listing. ReviewAdaptor is listed and has the same symbol from the question (a circle that is 75% blue and 25% green). On the right is the code for the ReviewAdaptor class. The class is defined as abstract.]

Comment: Where did you find that? In the link in the question (and in my IntelliJ as well) abstract classes have the blue circle, a C in it and two bars on the sides.

Comment: i just made few classes after when i declared the class abstract then the symbol changes to that whats mentioned.

Comment: Thank you. you are right.Strange because IntelliJ help says the abstract class symbol is "the blue circle, a C in it and two bars on the sides".